# What are the disadvantages of using SOAP services?

Tags: soap

What are the disadvantages of using SOAP services?

Comment: As compared to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes from this wikipedia article: [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Disadvantages)

*Because of the verbose XML format, SOAP can be considerably slower than competing middleware technologies such as CORBA. This may not be an issue when only small messages are sent.[7] To improve performance for the special case of XML with embedded binary objects, the Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism was introduced.*

*When relying on HTTP as a transport protocol and not using WS-Addressing or an ESB, the roles of the interacting parties are fixed. Only one party (the client) can use the services of the other. Developers must use polling instead of notification in these common cases.*